# Adding key to a dictionary only if the value exists

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm requesting data from an API that returns a JSON formatted as,

```json
{
   "a":"1",
   "b":{
      "c":{
         "d":"2",
         "e":"3"
      },
      "f":"4"
   },
   "g":"5",
   "h":"6",
   "i":"7",
   "j":"8",
   "k":"9",
   "l":"10"
}
```

Unfortunately, this is not the ideal format I wish to see and is inconsistent with some other endpoints. I may wish to reformat this as,

```json
{
   "a":"1",
   "c":{
      "d":"2",
      "e":"3"
   },
   "properties": {
      "f":"4",
      "g":"5",
      "h":"6",
      "i":"7",
      "j":"8",
      "k":"9",
      "l":"10"
   }
}
```

I was able to easily reformat this by creating a function that did something like this,

```py
def format(data: dict) -> dict:
   return {
       "a": data["a"],
       "c": data["b"]["c"],
       "properties": {
           "f":data["f"],
           "g":data["g"],
           "h":data["h"],
           "i":data["i"],
           "j":data["j"],
           "k":data["k"],
           "l":data["l"],
       }
    }
```

Now, the API itself only returns some properties if the user asks for it. So the user may or may not request some of the fields under `properties` aforementioned, even more, these features might increase in the future or decrease as well.

This breaks my code if the user does not request all the properties and only some. As a quick solution, I changed the above for each properties to be set accordingly,

```py
       "properties": {
           "f":data["f"] if "f" in data else None,
           "g":data["g"] if "g" in data else None,
           "h":data["h"] if "h" in data else None,
           "i":data["i"] if "i" in data else None,
           "j":data["j"] if "j" in data else None,
           "k":data["k"] if "k" in data else None,
           "l":data["l"] if "l" in data else None,
       }
```

The problem with this is as before - these properties might keep increasing in the future to maybe 10 to 20, or even 40 features in the `properties` property, thus becoming repetitive. As a side effect as well, I have to run a loop after creating this new format to delete all keys that have values `None`.

Ideally, I would like solution where the `key:value` pair only becomes part of the `properties` if the value exists, but I could not think of an easy or ideal pythonic solution that would make this look like clean code.

I considered that creating an object that has internal properties with values of `None`, and doing the deletion right after that in a loop was "repetitive" - I would be basically creating a dictionary object, then deleting parts of it immediately right after, which doesn't make sense to me. This should be done in a single step, not two different pieces of code. I'm concerned this may not make immediate obvious sense to a future developer until they realize the nature of the API.

Thanks!

Comment: You could dynamically set the properties, i.e. loop over the desired keys and set them

Comment: so except `a` & `b` all other should go to properties?

Comment: I just remembered about dictionary comprehension after reading your comment, @MichalBurgunder. I posted an answer, do you think they answer the question? I guess I just needed a bit of rubber duck debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method of doing this is doing dictionary generation. Whatever the number of `properties`, I know what will never be part of it, namely `a`, `b`, `c` keys.

So I could write it out as,

```py
`properties`: {
    k:v for (k,v) in data.items() if k not in ['a', 'b', 'c'] 
}
```

I think this might work.